# How can I select only the top 10 rows (inside STUFF) then overflow the next 10 to the next row and so-on?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

Let's say I have a query where in one column, I'm stuffing a group of returned items together with a caret delimiter between each, and subsequently repeating delimeters when the number of items returned is fewer than 10 (9-delimeters total regardless of the number total items).

```
SELECT 
    so.Client_Name + '|' + 
    STUFF((SELECT '^' + CAST(SUB.itemId AS VARCHAR(25)) AS [text()]
            FROM Table_1 SUB
            WHERE SUB.clientId = so.clientId AND SUB.repID = so.repId AND SUB.orderPlaced = 0
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 1, '' ) AS 'col1'
FROM Table_1 so
```

This returns something like:

```
Test Client|Item_1^Item_2^Item_3^Item_4^Item_5^Item_6^Item_7^Item_8^Item_9^Item_10^Item_11^Item_12^Item_13
Client Two|Item_1^Item_2^Item_3^Item_4^Item_5^Item_6^Item_7^Item_8^Item_9^Item_10^Item_11^Item_12^Item_13^Item_14^Item_15
```

Whereas I require:

```
Test Client|Item_1^Item_2^Item_3^Item_4^Item_5^Item_6^Item_7^Item_8^Item_9^Item_10
Test Client|Item_11^Item_12^Item_13^^^^^^
Client Two|Item_1^Item_2^Item_3^Item_4^Item_5^Item_6^Item_7^Item_8^Item_9^Item_10
Client Two|Item_11^Item_12^Item_13^Item_14^Item_15^^^^^
```

And so on...

Comment: why don't you do this in the presentation layer, it would be fast and more appropraite

Comment: I'd love to, the "presentation layer" is that someone takes these files and imports them into an archaic system that doesn't accept any other format.